# Load existing Geofire location if one exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I would like Geofire to do one of two things; 1 - Look for a venue location in Firebase and if none exists, 2 - Create one.

So to clarify:

1. User creates a post based on the current venue.
2. Geofire checks to see if it already has a venue (Long and Lat cocoordinates) on record for that geolocation. If it **DOES** have that location stored in Firebase then it takes the user's new post and **ADDS** it to the same venue.
3. If Geofire **DOES NOT** detect a location in Firebase it creates a new venue and attaches the post to it.

I have separated my venue details from my Geofire coordinates but I dont understand how do I get Geofire to differentiate between whether an entry for this location does or does not exist within Firebase.

At the moment when I run my app it creates a new entry every time as per the screen-grab below, which is obviously not what I want.

[image: multiple entries with identical locations]

Here is the code:

First I set the reference for the name and the directory (I set them seperately because I use the name ref in a few instances)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    geoFireNameRef = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId()
    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("PostLocations").child("Coordinates")
    geoFire = GeoFire (firebaseRef: geoFireRef)
}
```

and then in my post method I call:

```
func savePost () {
     let location = CLLocation.init(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!) //Get Coordinates
     geoFire.setLocation(location, forKey: self.geoFireNameRef.key)// Save Coordinates 
postLocationDB.child(self.geoFireNameRef.key).setValue(locationDictionary) // Save Venue Details
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code you have written?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added the code

Comment: @Brewsky Where, in your code, are you actually "checking to see if it already has a venue (Long and Lat cocoordinates) on record for that geolocation"?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I was going to use var circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 0.6) but I was hoping there was something simpler. Is this the only solution?

Comment: @Brewsky I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand that you want to check if there is a venue with an existing couple of coordinates. What I would suggest is to store this couple under your Coordinates/{venueId} node as an extra field which is composed by the two coordinates, like the following:

```
- Coordinates
   - -LAWR2LH.....
     - l
        - 0: 22.345
        - 1: 22.345
     - compoundL: "22.345-22.345"
```

and then directly query the Real Time Database with a query that combines queryOrderedByChild and queryEqualToValue in order to find if a Coordinates/Venue node with compoundL = 22.345-22.345 is already existing.

Comment: I'm quite new to Firebase, would that be something like: postRef.queryEqualToValue("22.345-22.345", childKey: "Coordinates").observeSingleEvent( ... )?

Comment: @Brewski Actually I am not qualified at all in swift... so I prefer not to answer because there is the risk I give a wrong indication... From the documentation you should be able to find the solution. look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data. You have to combine queryOrderedByChild and queryEqualToValue. Good luck!

Comment: @Brewski To be complete: since my proposed solution is based on the structure of the Real Time Database, I allowed myself to answer to your question even if I don't have any swift competencies. Note that I have tested the proposed solution with JavaScript.