# How does one efficiently search through nested user post data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

this question has had me stunned for a bit and I come here to see if anyone has solved this case I'm working on.

Here's my database structure.

```
database
    posts
        userId
            postId
                title: "asd"
    postGeo
        g: "x"
        l:
            0: 'lat'
            1: 'long
```

I use, `geoFire.queryAtLocation(userLocation, radius);` to query every post id within the specified geofenced area. I store each postId in range into its own list. 
I then use this list to retrieve the post info.

My question, What is the most efficient way to query OR REORGANIZE my data so that I don't have to loop through EVERY post?

Ideas in air, restructure by zip-code, then query within that zip. That way I only loop through the set of data within that range. I feel there is an easier-should-be-apparent way of doing this I don't see. Maybe you could help?

```
database
    posts
        zipCode
            userId
                postId
                    title: "asd"
    postGeo
        g: "x"
        l:
            0: 'lat'
            1: 'long
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you do the geo query, you get back a key for each record and then you should have your data structured so you can just pull out that record, there should be no need to search or reorganise the data.

So if you want all the postIds, the your data for posts will be

```
Database
   Posts
       PostId
          userId
               Title
```

Comment: The only difference is that my data is organized by posts->userId->postId->info. I organize this way to easily access each users posts. The conflict is that the postId is nested within the userId. This being the case, the only way I can think of accessing it Is by looping through and checking if the ID im looking for is within it.

Comment: Should I not organize by posts->userId->postId->info? and instead posts->postId->userId->info

Comment: It’s nosql you can have both! Then when you do a geo query you look up one path and when you list all the posts by user you look up the other path.... there is no need to normalize data in nosql, and data is cheap so no need to have only one copy. Just when you write the post, you need to write it to both locations!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to denormalize your data and have the two data structures **in parallel** in the database. This is quite a classic approach with NoSQL databases.

So you would have (as is):

```
database
    posts
        userId
            postId
                title: "asd"
```

and you would add another node like:

```
database
    posts
        zipCode
            postId
                title: "asd"
```

In such a way you can efficiently query in two different ways.

The only drawback with this method is that you have to keep the two nodes in sync. But this can easily be done by writing to the two database nodes simultaneously, using the update method as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

---

Just an extra side note: you may be interested by looking at this post [Load existing Geofire location if one exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966895/load-existing-geofire-location-if-one-exists/49977746#49977746)

Comment: @Pacifici did you have the time to look at this solution?